# Displaying a video from a cell in full screen Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, video

So what I am trying to do is I have a UICollectionViewController with cells of images and videos and I want it so that when you tap on the video it plays the video in full screen. I have already made this for the images, however I am not quite sure how to do this for the videos? So with the images, you tap on the image (cell) and the image goes to the center of the screen with a black background view. I would like to incorporate the same thing but with videos, and of course the video will play etc...

I am fetching the video from Firebase.

Code on what I have for the image:

```
import UIKit
 import Firebase
 import MobileCoreServices
 import AVFoundation

   class ImagesAndVideosController: UICollectionViewController,  UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

lazy var messageImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleZoomTap)))

    return imageView
}()



 func handleZoomTap(_ tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if message?.videoUrl != nil {

        return
    }

    if let imageView = tapGesture.view as? UIImageView {

            self.chatLogController?.performZoomInForStartingImageView(imageView)
    }
}

 var startingFrame: CGRect?
 var blackBackgroundView: UIView?
 var startingImageView: UIImageView?

 func performZoomInForStartingImageView(_ startingImageView: UIImageView) {

    self.startingImageView = startingImageView
    self.startingImageView?.isHidden = true

    startingFrame = startingImageView.superview?.convert(startingImageView.frame, to: nil)

    let zoomingImageView = UIImageView(frame: startingFrame!)
    zoomingImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    zoomingImageView.image = startingImageView.image
    zoomingImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    zoomingImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleZoomOut)))

    if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        blackBackgroundView = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
        blackBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        blackBackgroundView?.alpha = 0
        keyWindow.addSubview(blackBackgroundView!)

        keyWindow.addSubview(zoomingImageView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.blackBackgroundView?.alpha = 1
            self.inputContainerView.alpha = 0

            // math?
            // h2 / w1 = h1 / w1
            // h2 = h1 / w1 * w1
            let height = self.startingFrame!.height / self.startingFrame!.width * keyWindow.frame.width

            zoomingImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: height)

            zoomingImageView.center = keyWindow.center

        }, completion: { (completed) in
            //                    do nothing
        })

    }
}
 func handleZoomOut(_ tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let zoomOutImageView = tapGesture.view {
        //need to animate back out to controller
        zoomOutImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        zoomOutImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            zoomOutImageView.frame = self.startingFrame!
            self.blackBackgroundView?.alpha = 0
            self.inputContainerView.alpha = 1

        }, completion: { (completed) in
            zoomOutImageView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.startingImageView?.isHidden = false
        })
    }
}
```

}

I am sorry if the code I have presented doesn't make much sense, I am sure you all know that this stuff is super confidential so I had to kind of cut and paste enough to show but not all of it. So again I apologize. 
I also have a play button so when there is a video that loads into the collection view it knows and puts a play button on top of it so that the video will play, however the video plays inside of the cell, that is why I want it to go to the center (like you see in most applications).

Thank you SO MUCH!! I hope I have provided enough information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have create this method for playing a video.

```
    func playVideo() {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video", ofType:"mp4") else {
        debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
        return
    }
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player
    present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It looks like this is what I am looking for! I will try this out tomorrow and update.

Comment: welcome, I have added this same code on my project it works fine. Do update me.

Comment: Please dont forget to copy your video file by clicking Project --> Build Phase ---> copy bundle resources and add your video here.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. My first problem is when I put the present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }

Comment: it says "use of unresolved identifier present" I'm not sure why? and also I am confused on the build phases thing. I am importing all the videos (and images) from firebase they are not local videos, so do I have to do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: I am pretty sure the issue is because I made this function in a different view controller. I made this in a UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: forget about what I said, I figured it out. Thank you so much that was exactly what I was looking for!!